# Error CS0176 with mouse_event and referencing values in the the same class from another class

Tags: c#, windows, mouse, flags, user32

I'm currently trying to call mouse_event from user32.dll but I keep getting error CS0176. I have had a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0176) of it but it has not been quite helpful... What am I doing wrong?

*Mouse class values*

```
/// <summary>
/// Common values for mouse_event.
/// </summary>
public static uint M_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
public static uint M_LEFTUP = 0x04;
public static uint M_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
public static uint M_RIGHTUP = 0x10;
public static uint M_MOVE = 0x01;
```

*Mouse class mouse_event wrapper*

```
public static void MouseEvent(uint flag)
{
    MousePoint position = GetCursorPosition();
    mouse_event(
        (uint)flag,
        position.X,
        position.Y,
        0,
        0
    );
}
```

*Other class: how I am calling it*

```
private MouseAPI mouseAPI_Process = new MouseAPI();
private void Click(int holdDelay)
{
    mouseAPI_Process.MouseEvent(MouseAPI.M_LEFTDOWN);
    Thread.Sleep(holdDelay);
    mouseAPI_Process.MouseEvent(MouseAPI.M_LEFTUP);
}
```

Is there any way I could fix this and/or what am I doing wrong?
I also get the same error when using `enum`s.

(Sorry for the bad title.)

Answer (score 0):

**I managed to fix it!**
So I found out that it was asking for me to turn `mouseAPI_Process` into `MouseAPI`.
Sorry for my stupidity!